# How to use Gelato SyncFee method with Safe wallet?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gasless, gelato

I am trying to make gasless transaction using [Relay Kit](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit).

There are two options to pay for transactions

1. Gelato 1Balance
2. Gelato SyncFee

Everything works perfect with first method, but I can't understand how to make second method works. There is no code example in the tutorial.

By Gelato SyncFee [docs](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/relay/non-erc2771/callwithsyncfee) contract that can be called with it must inherit GelatoRelayContext or GelatoRelayFeeCollector to be able to access fee, feeToken and feeCollector params that add to the end of calldata. But Safe contract do not inherit neither of them, but can accept this arguments as params to [execTransaction](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/7a77545f288361893313af23194988731ee95261/contracts/Safe.sol#L139). It is not a big problem to pass them as argument, but I can't find how can I get feeCollector.

So is it possible to use SyncFee with Safe wallet?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?